# manually install package in virtual env and pip requirements know

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install packages within virtual-env

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, I had to download and install 2 packages from source

```
antlr4-python2-runtime 4.5.2.1

tar xvfz antlr4-python2-runtime-4.5.2.1.tar.gz 

cd antlr4-python2-runtime-4.5.2.1

python setup.py install
```

But now it shows me this error:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement antlr-python-runtime>=3.1.3 (from Intellect==1.4.9->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
```

Comment: Did you activate virtualenv ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's happening (given the provided information is not enough), but from a search in PyPI, it looks that those are 2 different packages:

Version 4 [antlr4-python2-runtime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/antlr4-python2-runtime/4.4.1)

and

Version 3 [antlr_python_runtime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/antlr_python_runtime)

So, it seems you installed the wrong package.

**Note:** Also make sure that you are running `python setup.py install` with the virtualenv activated.